# Function on Touchable Opacity press not called even if button gets pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsx

i used to write some code for a list of Touchable Opacity, integrated in a search.

it shall be a simple searchinput field in React-Native.

its task is if the touchable opacity in the list of search results gets pressed it should replace the text in the textfield and return the value to its parent.

i already asked chatgpt for support but it failed and so now human intelligence is needed :D

May you help me fix this issue?

so now if i type some text it gets logged on the console and saved on removing focus.

now when i click on a search result, there should be also a console.log event triggered, which is not done to any point of time.

i cannot trigger the onPress event in the **touchable Opacity** in line **109**

What went wrong, what disables me to call it on click?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Keyboard,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

const ExpandableSearchField = ({
  initialValue,
  readOnly,
  searchResults,
  handleTextChange,
  onSave,
  title,
  containerWidth = "100%",
}) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState(initialValue);
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState(searchResults);
  const [selectedResultIndex, setSelectedResultIndex] = useState(-1);
  const [isBlinking, setIsBlinking] = useState(false);

  const textInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleInputChange = (newText) => {
    setText(newText);
    handleTextChange(newText);
    const newFilteredResults = searchResults.filter((result) =>
      result.toLowerCase().includes(newText.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredResults(newFilteredResults);
  };

  const handleResultPress = (result, index) => {
    setIsBlinking(true);
    setText(result);
    handleTextChange(result);
    onSave(result);
    setSelectedResultIndex(index);
    setExpanded(false);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsBlinking(false);
    }, 300);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setSelectedResultIndex(-1);
    }, 600);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setText(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { width: containerWidth }]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={1}
        style={[
          styles.textInputContainer,
          expanded && styles.expandedTextInputContainer,
          {
            height: expanded ? "auto" : 40,
            width: expanded ? "100%" : "90%",
          },
        ]}
        onPress={() => {
          if (!readOnly) {
            setExpanded(true);
            textInputRef.current.focus();
          }
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          ref={textInputRef}
          style={[
            styles.textInput,
            readOnly && styles.readOnly,
            expanded && { flex: 1 },
            expanded && { maxHeight: 40 * 2 },
            expanded && styles.expandedTextInput,
          ]}
          value={text}
          onChangeText={handleInputChange}
          onFocus={() => {
            if (!readOnly) {
              setExpanded(true);
            }
          }}
          onBlur={() => {
            if (!readOnly) {
              setExpanded(false);
            }
          }}
          editable={!readOnly}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {searchResults && searchResults.length > 0 && expanded && (
        <ScrollView style={styles.searchResults}>
          {filteredResults.map((result, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index}
              onPress={() => {
                handleResultPress(result, index);
                console.log(index); // Dieser Teil loggt den Index in der Konsole
              }}
            >
              <View>
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.resultText,
                    selectedResultIndex === index &&
                      isBlinking && {
                        backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
                      },
                  ]}
                >
                  {result}
                </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    overflow: "hidden",
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
  expandedTextInputContainer: {
    minHeight: 100,
    height: "auto",
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  readOnly: {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
    color: "#000000",
  },
  searchResults: {
    marginTop: 10,
    maxHeight: 160,
  },
  resultText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "lightgray",
  },
});

export default ExpandableSearchField;
```

here is some relevant code from the parent element.

The Parent Element calls the

```
ExpandableSearchField
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";


import ExpandableSearchField from "./Modules/TextProcessing/ExpandableSearchField";


export default function LoggedInView({
  debugLevel,
  styles,
  handleLogout,
  handleBarcodeScanned,
  QR_Text,
  setQR,
}) {

  const [searchBrandResults, setSearchBrandResults] = useState([
    "Renault",
    "Porsche",
    "Ferrari",
    "Opel",
    "Toyota",
    "Lamborghini",
    "Merzedes",
    "Fiat",
    "Tesla",
    "Koenigsegg",
    "Lotus",
    "Dacia",
  ]);
  const [brandSearchQuery, setBrandSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [filteredBrandSearchResults, setFilteredBrandSearchResults] = useState(
    []
  );
  const [searchBrandReadOnly, setBrandSearchReadOnly] = useState(false);

  const handleBrandSave = (modifiedText) => {

    console.log("Saved:", modifiedText);
  };

return (
 style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    width: "100%",
  }}>
  <ExpandableSearchField
    initialValue={brandSearchQuery}
    readOnly={searchBrandReadOnly}
    searchResults={searchBrandResults}
    handleTextChange={handleBrandTextChange}
    onSave={handleBrandSave} // Pass the updated handler here
    maxSearchResults={10}
    maxShownSearchResults={4}
    title="Marke"
    containerWidth="45%"
  />
</View>

);
}
```

Thanks for your help <3